# JS String Reformat

Tags: javascript, string

I want to change the following url:

```
`http://en.savefrom.net/#url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx`
```

into

```
`http://www.website.my/p/test.html?id=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx`
```

Is there a JavaScript or Jquery solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it will always be these exact patterns, you can write:

```
var newUrl = 'http://www.website.my/p/test.html?id=' +
              oldUrl.split('#url=')[1];
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1541872p/1/).

Comment: how to apply? Can you make it in jsfiddle.net